# ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(167)] Failed to launch GPU process in CefSharp

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

Im trying to use CefSharp in WinForm . when i run it in my system its not Work and get the below error:

[0418/050642.894:ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(248)] eglCreateContext failed with error EGL_BAD_ALLOC
[0418/050642.894:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(2049)] eglCreatePbufferSurface failed with error EGL_BAD_ALLOC
[0418/050642.902:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(229)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0418/050643.125:ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(248)] eglCreateContext failed with error EGL_BAD_ALLOC
[0418/050643.125:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(2049)] eglCreatePbufferSurface failed with error EGL_BAD_ALLOC
[0418/050643.126:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(65)] gl::GLContext::CreateOffscreenGLSurface failed
[0418/050643.126:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(273)] Could not create surface for info collection.
[0418/050643.126:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(75)] CollectGraphicsInfo failed.
[0418/050643.131:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(229)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0418/050643.135:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(167)] Failed to launch GPU process.

Can Any idea?

Comment: What version are you using? What OS? What GPU? If you open chrome://gpu in Chrome does it look like GPU acceleration is disabled?